# How many $5$-digit numbers less than $43205$ do not contain any digits greater than $6$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm not sure how to solve this question.

The only starting point I've thought of is $3 \times 7^4$ because one case would involve the first digit being either $1, 2$ or $3$, and the remaining $4$ digits would each have $7$ number possibilities.

Would someone be able to explain how to approach this question please?

Comment: Your way is a good start but you also have to consider numbers like $43204$.

Comment: Your approach is perfect. What more do you need?

Answer (score 4):

The total number of positive integers that are less than $43025$ using only digits between 0 and 6 is that same sequence of digits, interpreted as a base 7 number.
$$N_{tot} = 43025_7   $$
but $7^4 = 10000_7$ of these will have a leading digit of zero and so do not qualify as 5 digit numbers.
so
$$ N_{5 \text{ digits }}= 43025_7 - 10000_7= 33025_7   $$

It is interesting to note that the answer is the same no matter what base the question is posed in (as long as the base is 7 or greater)

For instance,  the number of 5 digit hexadecimal numbers that are less than $43025_{16}$ and that can be made using only digits between 0 and 6 is also $33025_7$

Answer (score 2):

Your start is perfect.  There are $3\times 7^4$ $5$ digit numbers strictly less than $40000$ that do not contain a digit more than $6$.

So now count how many there are between $40000$ and $43205$.   If take the second digit can be $0,1,2$ there are $3\times 7^3$ such numbers between $40000$ and $42999$.

So now count how many there are between $43000$ and $43205$ and ... well, continue. If we take the third digit to be $0$ or $1$ there are $2\times 7^2$  numbers between $4300$ and $43199$.

Now we just need the numbers between $43200$ and $43205$ (exclusive) and there are clearly $5$ of those (as we want numbers *strictly* less than $43205$... so we want $43200, 43201,43202,43203$ and $43204$).

So there are  $3\times 7^4 + 3\times 7^3 + 2\times 7^2 + 5$.

....

But you know.... This is basically counting in base $7$.

Every $5$ digit base $7$ number between $10000_7$ through $43205_7$ will be listed.

And So there will be $43205_7 - 10000_7$ such numbers.

And that is $43205_7 - 10000_7 (4\times 7^4 + 3\times 7^3 + 2\times 7^2 + 0 \times 7 + 5\times 7^0 ) - 7^4  = 3\times 7^4 + 3\times 7^3 + 2\times 7^2 + 5=33205_7$

.....

This basically demonstrates *why* we can express numbers in a decimal base.

Comment: "the numbers between 43200 and 43205 and there are clearly 6 of those" - true, but only 5 of these are less than 43205.

Comment: No, between $43200$ and $43205$ *inclusive* are ..... Oh, googly... you are right.  We were doing *strictly* less than, weren't we....

Answer (score 1):

You got off to a good start with $3\times7^4$.  Add $3\times7^3+2\times 7^2+5$

Comment: why not $3 \times 7^3 + 2 \times 7^2 + 5$ ? shouldn't we allow those digits to be zero ?

Comment: How did you get 2x7^3 + 7^2+5? I can't figure out how to get there :(

Comment: 43205.  Left digit is 4 - max next digit is 3 so $3\times7^3$.  After 43 - max next digit is 2 so $2\times7^2$.  After 432 next digit is 0 - no more powers of $7$.  Final digit is 5 - allowing $0\to 4$ i.e. $5$..

Comment: @WW1 - you are right.  I corrected the answer.